# How to make &:hover accessible? Can i use focus and hover together?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

We have a dropdown menu, that is CSS only and a bit convoluted by now. It would take time to refactor the whole thing to use JS focus which i am aware is possible.

I want to make my dropdown accessible. I am using SCSS with `&:hover` in order to have the menu drop down. Is there a way to say `&:hover OR &:focus` within SCSS?

Comment: Yes, `&:hover, &:focus { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if a user hovers or focuses on an element. That's why you can use the `AND`
operator in scss, or simply put, a comma:

```
&:hover, &:focus{
    //styles for both the hover and the focus state
}
```